# Why does webdriveio getText method return an array?

Tags: webdriver-io

The documentation on the website indicates it is supposed to return a string.
Is the array representative of each element found? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to confirm without seeing the actual code used, but if you send a selector that matches multiple elements, it will return an array of strings for each element.